# Thunderbird: Mails are not visible in inbox or appear twice?

Tags: thunderbird

Thunderbird Version: 2.0.0.23 (20090812)

Some mails appear twice in the inbox. Other are not visible at all but can be found when searching for their subject (which requires to know the subject in the first place ;)

Does anybody know a fix for this?

**Solution:**

This seems to be a known problem that just happens from time to time. As Abhinav suggests the solution seems to be to recreate the index.
I've found more infos here:

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Disappearing_mail#Common_problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following (backup the files first, please)

- Close thunderbird
- Go to the profile directory, and delete the index file (.msf) for the folder in question
- restart thunderbird.

Has worked for me a few times. BTW, the issue generally occurs when using IMAP and interrupting download/sync of folders - esp when a large number of messages are being synced. Is this the case here too ?

Comment: Seems to work, thanks. Yes its an IMAP account with some large folders.

Comment: I was having an issue where *SOME* messages would *misteriously* not show up *at all*. If I went to the webmail and forwarded one of the messages that wasn't showing up, the new one wouldn't show up either. Renaming these files to end with .msf.bak did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

I tried every suggestion I found on the web.  None of them worked.  The repair button only works when executed, but does not fix permanently.

I reinstalled Thunderbird by un-installing, downloading, and reinstalling.  That did not correct not displaying messages.

**What works:**
Uninstall Thunderbird using

> Control Panel -> Programs -> Uninstall a Program

and also AND MOST IMPORTANT, delete AppData.

Here is a [link to the whole process](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-uninstall-thunderbird-completely-and-then-reinstall-it).