# Mozilla Thunderbird and redundant Inbox views

Tags: thunderbird, gmail

I have a user with Mozilla Thunderbird and we just put in a GMail account into his configuration (to add to what was already there).

He now has duplicate "folders" in his Inbox despite having only one account with that name. How do I fix this?

I found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/33469/thunderbird-mails-are-not-visible-in-inbox-or-appear-twice) but he doesn't have disappearing emails, just duplicate accounts.

I'll try rebuilding the index (recommended in [that question](https://superuser.com/questions/33469/thunderbird-mails-are-not-visible-in-inbox-or-appear-twice)) but I don't know if that will help.

Comment: The user "corrected" this by deleting his old account that he no longer needed (he only had two). I suspect an index rebuild would have done the same thing. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: I should note that the "old" account was not duplicated; just the new one - and only in the Inbox. Upon deleting the old account, everything was good again.